# jQuery/JSON content data loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loading

I'm a beginner in JS so...
I was searching for the answer but with no result at all.

I've got this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_p1").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p1.html");
    });
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_p2").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p2.html");
    });
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_p3").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p3.html");
    });
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_p4").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p4.html");
    });
});
```

and I wonder if there's a way to hold all this data in one JSON or another file instead of 4 .html files.

Question #2

That's a proper way to control the view? or It's not acceptable for serious webmasters.

sorry for my poor English :|

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can use normal links to navigate through 'p1.html' to 'p4.html', is there any specific reason for trying to do it with Javascript?

Comment: I want to load only <div class="container"></div> not whole page

Comment: Ok so, the answer is YES, of course you can put it all in one JSON. Then load that JSON in your page and instead of `load` use `innerHTML` and pass it the appropriate part of the JSON object

Comment: I would advise against trying to put your html into a JSON file though as it would be tedious to maintain and would need escaping in case the html contains double quote characters as that would break the JSON syntax if they were not properly escaped.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wants to load some data stored in a `JSON` file asynchronously into his page. To do that you need to substitute the `load` method with `html` and pass the appropriate part of the `JSON` as a parameter.

```
$("#load_p1").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").html(json[0]);
});
```

Sample `JSON` structure

```
json = '[{"p1":"<h1>Test</h1>"},{"p2":"<h1>Test2</h1>"}]'
```

Using jQuery to load the `test.json` file:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    $("#load_p1").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").html(json[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: But how I can pass an array to js from file like sites.json

Comment: You have a couple of options, can you use ES6 or Require.js in that project?

Comment: yes Require.js seems fine, I just want to load content with smooth fade in from jquery into container div. smth like an router but without routes in adress

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question is not very clear. However, you can put the all javascript things in a single file, like : *script.js* and inject the script in your *HTML* file (where you need to use this).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_p1").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p1.html");
    });

    $("#load_p2").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p2.html");
    });

    $("#load_p3").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p3.html");
    });

    $("#load_p4").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("p4.html");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) method allows for loading html fragments. You do this by specifying a css selector after the url to load. When jQuery encounters that selector it will look for a matching element in the retrieved html and only load that portion into the element.

For instance if in the html file you had

```
<div id="content1">
  content 1
</div>
<div id="content2">
  content 2
</div>
<div id="content3">
  content 3
</div>
```

And used

```
jQuery("div").load("all.html #content2")
```

It will just load the content2 div.

As a side note you don't need to put each `click()` call into separate `jQuery(document).ready()` calls you can put them into a single callback.